# Improving performance of code under real time data acquisition and understanding weird bug

Tags: python, performance, image-processing, optimization, pyqtgraph

I'm working with a physical experimental system to track its evolution in real time using a camera. Specifically, I trigger the camera to retrieve images in a rate of 2.5Hz, and so the efficiency of the system is crucial in order to keep up with the experiment.

My current program takes the first image in a dedicated folder, `path`, and asks the user to select a region of interest on which it performs the desired operation. Next, it calculates the mean brightness per pixel of an acquired image, and of a batch of n images, `img_round`.

The mean brightness per image batch is plotted in real time with respect to the number of iteration of `img_round`.

Currently, when I run the program on static data it works great. However, when I attempt to run it in the expected experimental setting of processing where the images are actively added to the folder, I get false values for the brightness in my plot.

In general, I'm afraid my code isn't as efficient as it could be, and I would like to optimize it as much as possible.

Please find the code below:

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time 
 
center = (0, 0)
radius = (0)
is_dragging_center = False
is_dragging_radius = False
global avg_brightness_per_img_round
avg_brightness_per_img_round = 0
 
img_round = 5
run_count = 0
 
brightness_history = []
std_history = []
func_history = []
global scatter_item
scatter_item = None
 
def update_display_image():
    global resized_image
    if resized_image is not None:
        display_image = resized_image.copy()
        cv2.circle(display_image, center, radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(display_image, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
 
class UpdateDisplaySignal(QtCore.QObject):
    update_display_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
 
update_display_signal_obj = UpdateDisplaySignal()
update_display_signal_obj.update_display_signal.connect(update_display_image)
 
 
def on_mouse(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global center, radius, is_dragging_center, is_dragging_radius
 
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if np.sqrt((x - center[0]) ** 2 + (y - center[1]) ** 2) < 20:
            is_dragging_center = True
        else:
            is_dragging_radius = True
 
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        is_dragging_center = False
        is_dragging_radius = False
 
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if is_dragging_center:
            center = (x, y)
        elif is_dragging_radius:
            radius = int(np.sqrt((x - center[0]) ** 2 + (y - center[1]) ** 2))
 
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
pw = pg.PlotWidget(title='Mean Brightness vs image round')
pw.setLabel('left', 'Mean Brightness')
pw.setLabel('bottom', 'Image round')
scatter = pg.ScatterPlotItem(size=10, pen=pg.mkPen(None), brush=pg.mkBrush(255, 0, 0, 120))
line = pg.PlotDataItem(pen=pg.mkPen(color=(0,0,255), width=2))
pw.addItem(line)
pw.addItem(scatter)
 
def update_scatter():
    global scatter_item
    indices, values = zip(*enumerate(brightness_history, start=1))
    x = list(indices)
    y = list(values)
 
    if scatter_item is None:
        scatter_item = pg.ScatterPlotItem(size=10, pen=pg.mkPen(None), brush=pg.mkBrush(255, 0, 0, 120))
        pw.addItem(scatter_item)
 
    if isinstance(x, int):  
        x = [x]  
 
    if len(x) > 1:
        line.setData(x=x, y=y)
        scatter.setData(x=x, y=y, symbol='o', size=10, pen=pg.mkPen(None), brush=pg.mkBrush(255, 0, 0, 120))
 
        for i, (xi, yi) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
            label = pg.TextItem(text=f'{yi:.2f}', anchor=(0, 0))
            label.setPos(xi, yi)
            pw.addItem(label)
            
win = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
win.setCentralWidget(pw)
win.show()
 
path = r'C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\images'
 
def calc_xray_count(image_path, center, radius):
    original_image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
 
    median_filtered_image = cv2.medianBlur(original_image, 5)
 
    mask = np.zeros(original_image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.circle(mask, center, radius, 255, thickness=cv2.FILLED)
 
    median_filtered_image += 1  # Avoid not counting black pixels in image
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(median_filtered_image, median_filtered_image, mask=mask)
 
    pixel_count = np.count_nonzero(result)
 
    img_brightness_sum = np.sum(result)
    img_var = np.var(result)
 
    if (pixel_count > 0):
        img_avg_brightness = (img_brightness_sum/pixel_count) -1 # Subtract back to real data
    else:
        img_avg_brightness = 0
 
    return img_avg_brightness, img_var
 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

image_files = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith('.TIF'):
        image_files.append(os.path.join(path, filename))
 
first_image_path = image_files[0]
image = cv2.imread(first_image_path)
 
scale_percent = 60 
width = int(image.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(image.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
colored_image = cv2.applyColorMap(gray_img, cv2.COLORMAP_PINK)
resized_image = cv2.resize(colored_image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
 
center = (resized_image.shape[1] // 2, resized_image.shape[0] // 2)
radius = min(resized_image.shape[1] // 3, resized_image.shape[0] // 3)
 
cv2.namedWindow("Adjust the circle (press 'Enter' to proceed)")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Adjust the circle (press 'Enter' to proceed)", on_mouse)
 
while True:
    display_image = resized_image.copy()
 
    cv2.circle(display_image, center, radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.circle(display_image, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
    cv2.imshow("Adjust the circle (press 'Enter' to proceed)", display_image)
 
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == 13: 
        break
 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            
center = (int(center[0] / scale_percent * 100), int(center[1] / scale_percent * 100))
radius = int(radius / scale_percent * 100)
 
img_round_brightness_sum = 0
img_round_var_sum = 0
 
def process_images():
    global run_count, img_round_brightness_sum, img_round_var_sum
 
    while run_count < len(os.listdir(path)):   
        for i, image_path in enumerate(image_files, start=1):
            img_avg_brightness, img_var = calc_xray_count(image_path, center, radius)
            img_round_brightness_sum += img_avg_brightness
            img_round_var_sum += img_var
 
            run_count += 1
 
            if run_count % img_round == 0:
                avg_brightness_per_img_round = (img_round_brightness_sum/img_round)
                deviation_per_img_round = np.sqrt(img_round_var_sum/img_round)
 
                brightness_history.append(avg_brightness_per_img_round)
                std_history.append(deviation_per_img_round)
 
                update_scatter()

                img_round_brightness_sum = 0
                img_round_var_sum = 0
 
                img_avg_brightness = 0
                img_var = 0
 
                QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
                QtCore.QThread.msleep(100)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    timer = QtCore.QTimer() 
    timer.timeout.connect(process_images)
    timer.start(100)  
    app.exec_()
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Summary: I'm seeking optimization advice, and an explanation for false image brightness values while in dynamic setting.

Comment: you mention a frequency of 2.5 which should be insanely easy to keep up with. Just having a look at your code, but it's a mess with lots of global variables and weird choices like adding 1 to count zeros. I think you should start by cleaning up the code first. Besides, if real-time performance is what you want, why are you working with files? have 2 threads, one of which stores the captured images and one of which does the processing on the fly and displays the results to the user. All of this would be easier if you give us the complete code an input image and desired output.

Comment: I see. I updated the question to include my full code. Regarding the addition and subtraction of one, I wanted to include counting the black pixels in the image. I know this is a rather silly solution, so please feel more than free to suggest elegant solutions.

I'm pretty new to Python, how could I implement threads in my code?

Comment: Is your mask a simple geometric shape (square, rectangle, circle, etc.) or is it a "blob"? if it's a simple shape, you can do that step much more quickly by just indexing.

Comment: Just echoing @OM222O comments - you shouldn't be wasting time  compressing images and saving to disk and re-loading in a real-time app.

Comment: I posted an answer that would be helpful for you, but I don't think it directly solves your issues. again, as long as you don't provide inputs (even if they're fake images generated using numpy random array) and your code is this messy, you can't expect us to do much. Update your question with cleaner code and provide inputs so the answers can be directly used rather than being general hints as to what you should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's really difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve they way you have written your code, so please clean it up. Here is an example and some suggestions for improvements but I quickly gave up on refactoring the entire thing. You can apply a LOT of cleanup and refactoring to this code, for example by breaking your functions into smaller units, and then chaining those functions. Using a class to save the state of your processor instead of relying on global variables everywhere, etc.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

class Processor:
    def __init__(self,img):
        self.img = img # Self.img can act as your image buffer
        self.center = (75,75) # I hard coded values but you can calculate and initialize center here
        self.radius = 20
        self.is_dragging_center = False # Initialize all of your global variables here
        self.is_dragging = False
        self.dragging_center = False
        
    def draw_circles(self, img): #Either explicitly pass the image or use self.img
        cv2.circle(img, self.center, self.radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(img, self.center, 5, (0, 0, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
    
    def resize_img(self,img, scale_percent=60):
        width = img.shape[1] * scale_percent // 100
        height = img.shape[0] * scale_percent // 100
        return cv2.resize(img, (width, height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    
    def transform_color(self, img, cma=cv2.COLORMAP_PINK):
        return cv2.applyColorMap(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), cmap)
    
    def on_mouse(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
        cx,cy = self.center
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            # <20 should probably not be hard coded?
            # if you want performance do you actually care about dragging in a perfectly circular radius?
            # For example using "if abs(x-cx) + abs(y-cy) < 20" creates a diamond pattern but it's 3 to 4x faster
            # you can also simplify this to ((x - cx) ** 2 + (y - cy) ** 2) < 400
            # "is_dragging_radius" looks to be : "not is_dragging_center", do you really need two variables here?          
#             self.is_dragging = True
#             self.dragging_center = ((x - cx) ** 2 + (y - cy) ** 2) < 400
            if np.sqrt((x - cx) ** 2 + (y - cy) ** 2) < 20:
                self.is_dragging_center = True
            else:
                self.is_dragging_radius = True
        # All of the "elif"s can be simplified to just "if"s
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
#             self.is_dragging = False
            self.is_dragging_center = False
            self.is_dragging_radius = False

#         if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and self.is_dragging:
#             if dragging_center:
#                 center = (x, y)
#             else:
#                 radius = int(np.sqrt((x - center[0]) ** 2 + (y - center[1]) ** 2))
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            if is_dragging_center:
                center = (x, y)
            elif is_dragging_radius:
                radius = int(np.sqrt((x - center[0]) ** 2 + (y - center[1]) ** 2))
                
p = Processor(np.zeros((150,150,3), dtype=np.uint8))
p.draw_circles(p.img)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(p.img)
plt.show()
```

regarding the performance issues and how to process the images while saving them to disk, you can do something like:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as TPE, wait
# below imports are only used in the second example
from collections import deque
from threading import Thread, Event
# below imports are just used for this example, you can ignore them
import time
from random import random, choice
from string import ascii_letters, digits
from threading import Lock

def generator(max_delay): # Acts as the data generator, i.e: a camera in your case
    alphabet = list(ascii_letters)+list(digits)
    while True:
        yield ''.join(choice(alphabet) for i in range(20))
        time.sleep(random()*max_delay)
        
        
def save(x, lock):
    time.sleep(random()*0.5)
    with lock:
        print(f'saved {x}')

def process(x, lock):
    time.sleep(random()*0.8)
    with lock:
        print(f'Processed {x} to {x[:10].swapcase()}')
        
def producer(generator, queue, event, lock):
    for x in generator:
        if event.is_set():
            break
        queue.append(x)
    with lock:
        print(f'{"*"*20} Done prodcuing. Shutting down. {"*"*20}')


lock = Lock() # Lock is used to make sure multiple threads don't print at the same time
############################## 
##############################
###     FIRST EXAMPLE      ###
##############################
##############################
# In this example we don't mind if we miss captured frames since we don't have a large enough memory to store
# all of the incoming data and our processing might be too slow to process in real time
g = generator(0.3)
with TPE() as executor:
    start = time.time()
    while (time.time()-start)<5: # Run experiment for 5 seconds
        x = next(g) # Get the next input form "camera"
        # Save the image and process it in parallel (you may want to pass a copy to be processed)
        futures = [executor.submit(save,x,lock), executor.submit(process,x,lock)]
        # Wait for saving and processing to finish before processing the next frame
        wait(futures)
        print('#'*50)
    print('Done processing and saving. Shutting down.')


print('_'*100)
print('_'*100)
print('_'*100)
print('_'*100)
############################## 
##############################
###     SECOND EXAMPLE     ###
##############################
##############################
# This second example deals with a case that your input rate is higher than your processing throughput
# If you can process everything in real time OR if you don't mind missing frames, then you can ignore this part.
# This is only advised if you have enough ram available to hold all the captured data


q = deque()
shutdown_event = Event()
t = Thread(target=producer, args=(generator(0.1), q, shutdown_event, lock))
t.start()

with TPE() as executor:
    start = time.time()
    while (time.time()-start)<5: # Run experiment for 5 seconds
        # If queue is empty, wait for it to be populated (in case that input rate is lower than processing throughput)
        while len(q)==0:
            pass
        x = q.popleft() # Get the next "frame" from the queue
        # Save the image and process it in parallel (you may want to pass a copy to be processed)
        futures = [executor.submit(save,x,lock), executor.submit(process,x,lock)]
        # Wait for saving and processing to finish before processing the next frame
        wait(futures)
        print('#'*50)
    # now that your experiment is done, shutdown the producer
    shutdown_event.set()
    # Keep processing until the queue is empty
    while len(q)!=0:
        x = q.popleft() # Get the next input form "camera"
        # Save the image and process it in parallel (you may want to pass a copy to be processed)
        futures = [executor.submit(save,x,lock), executor.submit(process,x,lock)]
        # Wait for saving and processing to finish before processing the next frame
        wait(futures)
        print('#'*50)
    print('Done processing and saving. Shutting down.')
t.join()
```

note that the second example continues processing even when the experiment is over and you have stopped capturing frames. It also outputs a lot more data since no input is missed (and the `max_delay` is 0.1 instead of 0.3 seconds).